# java.lang.NullPointerException on DefaultTableModel getModel()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have made a `JTable` with `DefaultTableModel`, I add data inside and everything, but when I try to retrieve it I get `NullPointerException` here:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)finishedSaleTable.getModel();
```

---

```
private DefaultTableModel finishedSaleModel;
private JTable finishedSaleTable;
```

---

```
public SaleUI() { 
String finishedSaleColumns [] = {"#", "Customer", "Employee",  "Products", "# Products", "Discount", "Price", "Date"};
        finishedSaleModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, finishedSaleColumns);
        finishedSaleTable = new JTable(finishedSaleModel){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        finishedSaleTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(85);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(90);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(75);
        finishedSaleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(125);
            JScrollPane finishedSaleTableScroll = new JScrollPane(finishedSaleTable);
}

private void finishedSaleClearList()
    {
        DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)finishedSaleTable.getModel();
        while(dm.getRowCount() > 0)
           dm.removeRow(0);
    }
```

Full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ui.SalesUI.finishedSaleClearList(SalesUI.java:641) // DefaultTableModel line
    at ui.SalesUI.finishedSaleUpdateList(SalesUI.java:674) // where I call the method
    at ui.SalesUI.<init>(SalesUI.java:248)
    at ui.SalesUI.main(SalesUI.java:752)
```

Comment: Please post more of your code as well as the full stacktrace for your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sounds more like the reference to `finishedSaleTable` is `null`, but without example code, it's impossible to be sure

Comment: I added the code I use

Comment: check to see if finishedSaleTable is null. I would do it both in the finishedSaleClearList() method and in the public SaleUI() constructor after you create it

Answer (score 1):

It can either be one of two things. Either: `finishedSaleTable` is null or something inside of the `getModel()` is. But like the other comments, there's nothing more we can tell you without the rest of the code.